# Ionic 3 - Erro ao gerar build --prod

Tags: ionic, npm

Não estou querendo gerar a versão --prod usando o comando "npm run build --prod". *(Fiz um script que diz que "npm run prod" significa "npm run build --prod", está no meu package.json)*

[Link do projeto completo](https://github.com/Vizoni/ionic2-firebase-chat)

[Link do package.json](https://github.com/Vizoni/ionic2-firebase-chat/blob/master/package.json)

`ionic info` :

[image: <code>Ionic Info</code>]

**ERRO:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

tente dar um "npm install Ionic2FirebaseChat@0.0.1 --save" ou deletar a pasta node_modules e dar um "npm install"

Comment: O primeiro comando deu um erro de 404, e deletar o node_modules e dar um npm install também não alterou o problema... Pelo que eu percebi é um erro relacionado a versão do CLI com o @ionic-native

Answer (score 0):

**CONSEGUI:**

Aparentemente eu tive que mudar a versão do firebase e angularfire2.

[Link do Commit](https://github.com/Vizoni/ionic2-firebase-chat/commit/df365b5ed82e278c5d95aa22c9b02791641e1a50)